# How to merge cells in Vaadin grid

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I wonder how I can merge in Vaadin 7.6 a group of cells for the same column name, where values in the cells would be replaced by a unique cell.

Right now, I only found how to merge headers and footers.

Tks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Vaadin Grid doesn't support that. As you noticed it's possible to merge cells on headers and footers but it's not supported on the actual content cells.