# Vaadin Multirow Cell in Table

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to add a table to my vaadin application with the following layout:

[image]

Is it possible to create multirow cells on Vaadin tables as you can see on the picture?

Thanks,
Cris.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Table merge cells - Vaadin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694324/table-merge-cells-vaadin)

Answer (score 1):

Per my knowledge, this is not possible so far neither with the [table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694324/table-merge-cells-vaadin) nor with the [grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34884375/how-to-merge-cells-in-vaadin-grid). As you'll notice in those 2 linked questions and the [docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-grid.html#components.grid.headerfooter.joining), while the grid allows for some header merging/joining, the table does not have any similar functionality. However, in the [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32694324/table-merge-cells-vaadin) there is a suggestion on how to simulate what you're looking for, using [grid layout](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/layout/layout-gridlayout.html).

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've seen thos questions. However, I need that the rows can be selected, and I'm not sure if I can simulate that with the grid layout approach.

Comment: @crigore No problem. You may be able to simulate it using `LayoutClickListener` and some CSS but you did not specify what the selection behaviour is. Depending on how it should look like, you could probably find another workaround, for example creating a new table in the grid layout for each of the 3 items in the group (maybe overkill but still a workaround). However the answer to your question is still _no, there's no easy way to do this with the regular table and/or grid_